# attribute sets choice

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I need to create XSD (version 1.0) to validate element with the following restrictions:

- it can have **optional** boolean attributes **A** *or* **B** (by this element can have no attributes at all). So **A** can be paired with **B**
- just required boolean **C** with default value set to true and ***without*** **A** *and* **B** attributes

So valid examples are:

```
<myelem A="1" B="0"></myelem>
<myelem A="1"></myelem>
<myelem C="1"></myelem>
```

But not:

```
<myelem A="0" C="1"></myelem>
```

I know that `xsd:choice` exists, but it can't have `attributeGroup` as a child.

Is there any way to achieve this restriction in XSD 1.0?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with attributes - if you can convert your attributes to elements then it is possible with xs:choice as you mentioned - Also see http://www.w3.org/wiki/Simple_attribute_implication